# ASP.Net Core - Eager Loading with Stored Procedure instead of Include

Tags: asp.net-core, dbcontext, eager-loading

Is there a way to implement eager loading by having a stored procedure return a result set that can then be automatically bound to a parent data object and its linked data objects?
I'm currently trying to do this with ASP.Net Core 2.0

Example:

For these Data Objects:

```
public class Address 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Street1 {get;set;}
    public string Street2 {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
    public string Region {get;set;}
    public string PostalCode {get;set;}
    public string Country {get;set;}
}
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}  
}
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public Address ShippingAddress {get;set;}
    public Address BillingAddress {get;set;}
    public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

can a controller make a call that returns many customers, similar to:

```
var recordSet = dbContext.Set<Customer>().FromSql("EXEC dbo.[GetCustomerInfo] @TokenDtime={0}", tokenDtime);
```

where dbo.[GetCustomerInfo] contains something like the following:

Query A - Bssic Join:

```
SELECT 
    c.[Id]           [CustomerId]                        ,
    c.[FirstName]    [CustomerFirstName]                 ,
    c.[LastName]     [CustomerLastName]                  ,
    sa.[Id]          [CustomerShippingAddressId]         ,
    sa.[Street1]     [CustomerShippingAddressStreet1]    ,
    sa.[Street2]     [CustomerShippingAddressStreet2]    ,
    sa.[City]        [CustomerShippingAddressCity]       ,
    sa.[PostalCode]  [CustomerShippingAddressPostalCode] ,
    sa.[Country]     [CustomerShippingAddressCountry]    ,
    sb.[Id]          [CustomerShippingAddressId]         ,
    sb.[Street1]     [CustomerShippingAddressStreet1]    ,
    sb.[Street2]     [CustomerShippingAddressStreet2]    ,
    sb.[City]        [CustomerShippingAddressCity]       ,
    sb.[PostalCode]  [CustomerShippingAddressPostalCode] ,
    sb.[Country]     [CustomerShippingAddressCountry]    ,
    p.[Id]           [ProductId]                         ,
    p.[Name]         [ProductName]                       ,
    p.[Price]        [ProductPrice]
FROM
    [Customer] c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Address] sa ON c.[ShippingAddressId] = sa.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Address] sb ON c.[BillingAddressId] = sb.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [CustomerProduct] cp ON c.[Id] = cp.[CustomerId]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Product] p ON cp.[ProductId] = p.[Id]
WHERE
    c.[TokenDtime] >= @TokenDtime
```

Query B - Multiple Recordsets:

```
SELECT 
    c.[Id]           [CustomerId]                        ,
    c.[FirstName]    [CustomerFirstName]                 ,
    c.[LastName]     [CustomerLastName]                  ,
    sa.[Id]          [CustomerShippingAddressId]         ,
    sa.[Street1]     [CustomerShippingAddressStreet1]    ,
    sa.[Street2]     [CustomerShippingAddressStreet2]    ,
    sa.[City]        [CustomerShippingAddressCity]       ,
    sa.[PostalCode]  [CustomerShippingAddressPostalCode] ,
    sa.[Country]     [CustomerShippingAddressCountry]    ,
    sb.[Id]          [CustomerBillingAddressId]          ,
    sb.[Street1]     [CustomerBillingAddressStreet1]     ,
    sb.[Street2]     [CustomerBillingAddressStreet2]     ,
    sb.[City]        [CustomerBillingAddressCity]        ,
    sb.[PostalCode]  [CustomerBillingAddressPostalCode]  ,
    sb.[Country]     [CustomerBillingAddressCountry]     
FROM
    [Customer] c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Address] sa ON c.[ShippingAddressId] = sa.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Address] sb ON c.[BillingAddressId] = sb.[Id]
WHERE
    c.[TokenDtime] >= @TokenDtime        

SELECT 
    c.[Id]           [CustomerId]                        ,
    p.[Id]           [ProductId]                         ,
    p.[Name]         [ProductName]                       ,
    p.[Price]        [ProductPrice]
FROM
    [Customer] c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [CustomerProduct] cp ON c.[Id] = cp.[CustomerId]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Product] p ON cp.[ProductId] = p.[Id]
WHERE
    c.[TokenDtime] >= @TokenDtime
```